# Strange Math 2.5

Tags: mathematics

My teacher has been giving even more confusing homework every since she found out about my online help. Today's assignment was supposed to be easy enough: only some factorization, kids' stuff. But when I received my sample problems, I realized that I would be needing some help again. So would you mind giving me assistance for another time?

$75678 = 47*96*13$
$53271 = 53*33*83$
$707821 = 11*31*76*7$
$236783 = 73*46*12*22*2$
$5769471 = \ ?$

Hint:

> The first step is of prime concern.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The answer is:

> $55 * 56 * 94 * 1$

Solution:

> Reverse the left hand side number. Find all prime factors. Sort them alphabetically. Separate them with "*" into 2 digit numbers. Example: 75678 -> 87657 = 479 x 61 x 3, after sorting = 479613, after separation = 47 * 96 * 13

Comment: Congratulations! Great Work : )